# Input field appear after selecting a check box. HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Twitter Bootstrap form that has 6 vertical check boxes. I need to have an input form field each time they select a checkbox. It could be in the form of a popup or maybe something that appears out to the right of the checkbox. I figure this is some kind of javascript function but I have no idea how to do so. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Each textbox if selected should have a field that pops up asking them for how many years experience they have in this certain field. This will info will be collected via $_POST variables. So each checkbox popup should have its own unique name so i can post it.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="positionsought">Position Sought</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-0" value="Cutting">
      Cutting
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-1" value="Sewing">
      Sewing
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-2" value="Upholstery">
      Upholstery
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-3" value="Frame Department">
      Frame Department
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-4" value="Mill Room">
      Mill Room
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-5">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-5" value="Cushion">
      Cushion
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="positionsought-6">
      <input type="checkbox" name="positionsought" id="positionsought-6" value="Any">
      Any
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, I'd start by Googling "javascript add input dynamically" to get an idea on how to manipulate the DOM

Comment: There's no `java` involved in here ...

Comment: A rough idea could be to create a textbox and set it's display property to none, then when any of the checkbox is checked, trigger a function and inside it make the textbox visible!

Comment: Also you need to post your HTML code atleast

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service - there are plenty of online tutorials on how to develop using javascript, and also how to write code to dynamically show/hide controls.  If you're having a specific issue with the code you've written (that can be easily replicated through code you provide) then come back to us

Comment: I understand that, i was asking for an approach not someone to write my code. Try to remember what it was like being new to the wild world of writing code, it can be quite overwhelming and the simplest of answers are often overlooked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you already have found an answer, I believe that this would work better for your situation since you say you will have 6 checkboxes. This dynamically creates input fields for each checkbox by their names and removes them when the checkbox is unchecked.

First add this function to each checkbox `onclick="dynInput(this);"`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onclick="dynInput(this);" />
```

and add this to wherever you would like the inputs to display.

```
<p id="insertinputs"></p>
```

Then simply add this javascript function to your head.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function dynInput(cbox) {
  if (cbox.checked) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = cbox.name;
    div.innerHTML = "Text to display for " + cbox.name;
    div.appendChild(input);
    document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);
  } else {
    document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
  }
}
</script>
```

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brL6gy7r/

Comment: You are right for my example this will work better. Do you know of any good resources that would teach someone new like me about javascript because obviously i need it.

Comment: Many people will recommend learning jQuery rather than JavaScript. It is based on JavaScript, and much easier to use. To fully understand it, though, it is best to have an understanding of JavaScript first.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow - NO NO NO... w3schools is **NOTHING** to do with W3C - they are playing on their name and should be avoided... please read http://w3fools.com

Comment: @freefaller wow, i did not know that. i've deleted my comment because i consider it harmful. thank you for enlightening me. still, w3schools is a pretty good resource for learning web technologies.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow, I appreciate your removal of the comment, but I would still question w3schools are a `good resource`.  w3schools is much better than it was, but it's still not `good`, however, the choice to recommend them is yours

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow You are correct in your comment and this answer i've linked to is a great way to explain the relationship between javascript and jquery. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122191/what-benefits-are-there-to-native-javascript-development/132357#132357 User3487244, as for places to learn Javascript, I would recommend w3schools.com or codeacademy.com

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript here to do the job. When the checkbox is clicked and checked (because you can also check out.) a dialog will pop-up with all input-fields you want. You can change the dialog part to your desires. but this part is your main function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#chkBox').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // create input field
    } else {
       // if checkbox is not checked.. dont show input field 
    }
  });
});
```

For a full demo on how to do this with a dialog, click this link and observe

http://jsfiddle.net/Runman44/5vy1m233/

Notice that you will need jQuery (and jQuery UI if you want to use the dialog like me)

Comment: If i use this method when they click submit will it try to submit the whole page or just what was typed into the input boxes will be saved and i can continue on my form?

Comment: I am having difficulty with your solution. When i click the submit button it does nothing. Here is my js [link](fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/wild_card05/q6jehbrt/) Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a zero-JavaScript version that is dead simple and works in [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). It takes advantage of the [`:checked`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked) pseudo-class and the [adjacency selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). It works with an arbitrary number of checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" />
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
    visibility:hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + input[type=text] {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[**here is the live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8hz26qw/)

If you prefer, you can use `display:none` and `display:inline` rather than the `visibility` property.

The example I've provided assumes that the text field immediately follows the checkbox in the markup, but some variant of sibling/child selectors can be used to select it no matter where it is, as long as it is either a sibling or child (direct or indirect) of the checkbox.

Comment: Its a good answer but i am using the Twitter Bootstrap that is hosted at their cdn. So i have no access to change the css.

Comment: You can put this in your own CSS. Any webpage can have multiple stylesheets -- in the case of a conflict, the most recently declared rule stands.

Comment: obviously you might want to apply some classes so you don't make every single text field on your page invisible. but other than that, this shouldn't have any conflict with bootstrap.